# ROS Answers SE migration: rosdoc_lite

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have groovy and i am using the rosdoc_lite for my documentation. The documentation is working but i get no  graphs.

How i can activate call or caller graphs ?

Or How i can config my doxygen config file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74320/rosdoc_lite/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-22**:
Are you running rosdoc_lite locally, or via the ROS wiki doc server? Is there an on-line link to your package's docs?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-22**:
I get graphs of header file includes: http://ros.org/doc/hydro/api/camera1394/html/dev__camera1394_8h.html Is that what you want?

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-22**:
yes locally, this header graph i get too. I want a call graph for function that i see which function he is calling like this [http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/](http://www-scf.usc.edu/%7Epeterchd/doxygen/)

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-22**:
I only have to modify my config doxygen file but i dont not how i can do this when i am using rosdoc_lite
CALL_GRAPH = YES
Generate a dependency graph for functions and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently took over maintenance for `rosdoc_lite`, but am not yet familiar with the code. Please bear with me while trying to figure this out.

Doxygen is invoked with a [template file that sets CALL_GRAPH = NO](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/blob/master/src/rosdoc_lite/templates/doxy.template#L1680). I don't see any option for overriding that template file or replacing it with one of your own. Some variables, such as FILE_PATTERNS, can have [per-package values](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Doxygen#rosdoc:_Default_Doxygen_Settings) defined in `rosdoc.yaml`, but CALL_GRAPH is not one of them.

The comments immediately before recommend enabling caller graphs only for selected functions, using the `\callergraph` command. Is that an option for you?

**UPDATE**: the main purpose of `rosdoc_lite` is automatically generating documentation for packages listed on the ROS wiki or similar destinations. The main reason for running it locally is to check updates to those docs before committing them.

If your documentation goals differ, running Doxygen directly may make more sense.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-25**:
ok i copied this doxygen config and used it with rosdoc_lite -t /path/to/config but i get a few errors

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-26**:
I think the -t option is for a tag file, not a doxy configuration file.

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-26**:
Same idea i ran Doxygen direct and get a good output. Thank you for your help